# REST web services: Symfony 2 vs silex

Tags: php, rest, symfony, silex

We're going to implement a set of REST web services in PHP. We've selected 2 frameworks to do that: Symfony 2 and Silex (micro-framework as a phar archive, based on Symfony2).

For now, there will be only a few services, with a few resources returned as GET, but the set of method will eventually grow and include other rest actions (put/post/delete).

here is the list of pros and cons I've got so far for these 2 frameworks

***Symfony2***

Pros:

- more powerful
- Doctrine ORM
- can debug with XDebug
- config in YML
- more used in the community
- more support
- autocompletion in IDE
- fast

cons:

- Need FOSBundle to do REST (?) (actually, I'd like to know if this is really useful)

**Silex**

Pros:

- lightweight
- seems easier to create REST urls (?)
- easier to deploy (phar archive)

Cons:

- no Doctrine ORM
- cannot debug (phar archive)
- no autocompletion in IDE
- config must be hardcoded
- may be a bit slower, as it's in a phar archive ?

Which one do you think is the best?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Personally I really like symfony 2, its easy to create REST urls using the annotations syntax,  in your controller you put something like

```
/**
 * @Route("/user/{id}", requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, defaults={"_format"="json"})
 * @Method({"GET"})
 */
 public function getUser($id) {
     ...
 }
 /**
 * @Route("/user", defaults={"_format"="json"})
 * @Method({"PUT"})
 */
 public function putUser() {
     ...
 }
```

Comment: We've decided to go with the Symfony option as well

Comment: What about https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle?

Answer (score 16):

Depends on the size of your project really and since you stated that it's quite small I would have chose Silex.

Almost all of the cons you list for Silex are ruled out when you [include silex through composer](http://packagist.org/packages/silex/silex). Then it just loads the Silex dependency inside vendors and you don't have the overhead of the phar nor the lack of code completion in your IDE. In fact [the PHAR distribution is deprecated](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/download).

As for Doctrine, Silex has a [built in Doctrine ServiceProvider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/doctrine.html) that seamlessly loads Doctrine DBAL in your Silex project. You can add DoctrineORM easily yourself or use one of the [3rd party serviceProviders](https://github.com/search?q=silex%20doctrine&type=Everything&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1) found on github.

I'm building a rather big REST API with Silex and haven't regretted a single thing starting off with Silex. You get a lot of the advantages of the Symfony2 components since silex is built with them and have a very lightweight rest-ready microframework without having to go through hours of yaml configuration and setting up.

And to be honest I must admit I'm not a huge fan of the annotations, annotations are fine but I think the examples be @mcfedr take it a little too far but that's just personal taste.

I hope I've debunked some of the prejudices you have about Silex. Give it a swing, you won't regret it. On the other hand, you probably won't regret Symfony2 either :)

Comment: Hi ChrisR. I was curious how you are creating you REST api documentation with your Silex project. Do you do it manually or have you found a kind of generator, like NelmioApiDocBundle for symfony2. Personally I like Silex, but I'm really considering Symfony2 just for the auto api doc generation.

Comment: I'm not autogenerating API docs unfortunately, that's on my todo list :)

Comment: @ChrisR can I ask how you got on with this project? Did you use just the DBAL or entities etc in your API?

Comment: you could use some third party doctrine orm service provider. I am using this https://github.com/dflydev/dflydev-doctrine-orm-service-provider